# Logging out the first time causes an unintentional click on the privileges link

Tags: bug, status-norepro

When I hover over the profile link, a box pops out showing links for "activity, privileges and logout".
The first time I hover, the box gets formed for the first time, so it's first a small box and then it loads all the content and it becomes a bigger box.
The trouble is that during the 1 second that it is a small box, a user would've already located the 'logout' link and will be moving the mouse pointer to click on it. By the time the mouse pointer reaches the logout link, the 'privileges' link also loads and the user ends up clicking on the privileges link.
This happens only the first time you log out once you've opened the browser.

Would it be possible for you to either switch positions of the 'logout' link with the 'activity' link so that the link does not jump suddenly and be an annoyance while logging out?

Comment: Hrm. I can't reproduce this. I get the "smaller box" first, but all three links (Activity, Privileges, and Logout) are already in it at that time and do not change position when the box resizes.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Anna -- this is no-repro for me

> I can't reproduce this. I get the "smaller box" first, but all three links (Activity, Privileges, and Logout) are already in it at that time and do not change position when the box resizes.

Hard to capture in a screenshot but basically the box starts out like this, then grows outward:

[image]

Comment: Tried it now. The box and the links show up on the first go. Tried it twice again and everything is fine. Looks like somebody fixed it. I've been having this problem ever since you guys changed the logout link a couple of months back. Seems to have been fixed now. Thanks :)

Comment: Err..no. The problem still exists. The last time (and posted the above comment) I tried, it was in Fedora12. This time I tried in Windows XP SP3, Firefox browser 4.0.1

Comment: This time it happened in Firefox 3.5.4 (for Linux) too. There is a jump when the box is first small and suddenly becomes big. Isn't the most important thing in the world, but it does get annoying while logging out. Don't tell me that you won't change it because you prefer that people don't log out of SO :-)

Comment: is there any reason you're using a version of Firefox that is 3+ major releases old?

Comment: No reason other than 'I don't use this particular computer (on which the old Firefox is) much'. In any case, the point is that the problem exists on old and new versions of Firefox. I've got an upvote too, so seems like someone else has also experienced it. I'm guessing you couldn't reproduce it because you have a much much faster internet connection.